# Android Mapbox Navigation - Sometimes does not initialize and other times crashes when the User is on the Same location

Tags: android, navigation, react-native, mapbox, native

I have a React Native Project that calls and Android Activity that contains the Mapbox Navigation SDK Embbeded Navigation (https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/examples/embedded-navigation/). Within React Native, I am already using lots of resources like consuming from Graph QL through Apollo Client. I have also make sure to turn on GPS and check for Internet Connection before navigating to the Android Activity.  Issues.

1) When I generate a Release and run it on my Android, the first time the Mapbox Navigation is launched, the Pointer would stay static, the Map gets rendered but the Navigation Instruction UI does not start. It is as the Fetch that gets the route never proceeds to start the Navigation.

Another issue that I have from time to time, is that when I set the Driving Mode to Traffic like going by Car, I start the Navigation Activity but if stay static on the same point for too much time, the app would crash, it is as if the Some Lister is actually waiting for my Location to change in order to proceed with the Navigation.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Edit:

For the first issue, I was able to move the following out of the Create() of the Activity, I was initializing a Real Time Library called PubNub for initializing the Map.

```
CameraPosition initialPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .target(new LatLng(ORIGIN.latitude(), ORIGIN.longitude()))
    .zoom(INITIAL_ZOOM)
    .build();
    navigationView.initialize(this, initialPosition);
```

Issue 2, stil persist. The current issue is that the Navigation Activity Crashes if the User does not move within the Naviga [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt69v.jpg)